# Are extra $(...) calls bad?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have code that pulls down a jQuery object, and then makes some further calls on it

```
$("a.postSyncLink").click(function () {
    var resultsTarget = $("span", $(link).parent().next());
    resultsTarget.html("<img style='position: absolute;' src='" + waitImgUrl + "'/><span>Sync in progress</span>");

    $.get($(this).attr("data-url"), function (returnVal) {
        resultsTarget.text(returnVal);
    });
});
```

Is it considered bad practice to subsequently (and unnecessarily) wrap that object in the jQuery function?  Does jQuery optimize superfluous calls like this?

```
$("a.postSyncLink").click(function () {
    var resultsTarget = $("span", $(link).parent().next());
    $(resultsTarget).html("<img style='position: absolute;' src='" + waitImgUrl + "'/><span>Sync in progress</span>");

    $.get($(this).attr("data-url"), function (returnVal) {
        $(resultsTarget).text(returnVal);
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not believe it does.  But why would you do this anyways?  resultsTarget is already a jQuery Object.  Is there a purpose or need for this?

Comment: @John - you're right.  It's just a result of being careless, and I was wondering if that was actually harmful in some way, or just silly and superfluous

Comment: This is what code reviews are for.  Development process can assist you in writing cleaner code.

Comment: @John - come on - this is something I see very often in jQuery code.  I'm not defending it, I'm just wondering if jQuert optimizes this away, or if it really matters.

Comment: @Adam Rackis... If your seeing this often in "Your" jQuery Code, then in My Opinion you should be taking a stronger approach to code reviews.  If your talking about "other's" sites having these issues, why are you worried about it?  The main point of view here is why do the same thing twice, such as `var somejQueryObject = $(someselector);  var samejQueryObject = $(somejQueryObject);`.  This is simply redundant and inefficient code that should be caught in code review.

Comment: @John - I've probably done it before because I assumed it didn't matter, and because I've never written a site that was so intense as to cause this to make a noticeable difference.  Shad's answer has disabused me of this misconception.

Comment: @kay....When I review a peers code  I take the time no only to understand the implementation but to correct mistakes of any nature.  If your not taking this approach it causes for difficulty in readability. In addition, efficiency issues can be spotted, before they are a problem.

Comment: @John - I agree with everything you said.  All I was saying was that it was an easy mistake to make, and an easy mistake to assume wouldn't matter.  That's why this site's so great: experts can quickly dispel specious assumptions like that.

Comment: If you want a sure-fire way to catch this problem, use a modified version of jQuery for development and [right about here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L85) do something like `if( selector instanceof jQuery.fn.init || context instanceof jQuery.fn.init ) console.warn( 'A jQuery object was passed as an argument to the jQuery constructor' );`

Comment: @RightSaidFred - that's really cool.  Can you please add as an answer?

Comment: @AdamRackis: Well, it doesn't really answer the question. More of a side note.

Comment: @rightSaid - I think it's a valuable side note that'd be valuable to future visitors.  Up to you though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If they aren't being used to clone the original jQuery object, then yes it's bad:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#cloning-jquery-objects

A jQuery object passed to `jQuery` is cloned, which is processor time I would not waste.

When storing a reference to a jQuery object I find it useful to prefix the variable name with a `$`, this helps me remember that it is a jQuery object, and doesn't need to be re-wrapped:

```
$("a.postSyncLink").click(function () {
    var $resultsTarget = $("span", $(link).parent().next());
    $resultsTarget.html("<img style='position: absolute;' src='" + waitImgUrl + "'/><span>Sync in progress</span>");

    $.get($(this).attr("data-url"), function (returnVal) {
        $resultsTarget.text(returnVal);
    });
});
```

Comment: I like the tip about prefixing with $.  I'll have to use that going forward.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand—just don't use it going backward, ok?

Comment: '$' shorthands 'jQuery'. So why is wide praxis to use it for 'object' remembrance? Rather use '_object' ...?

Comment: @roXon I use it because it reminds me that it is a _jQuery_ object; it's intuitive for me, and what's intuitive is faster. Certainly use whatever is most intuitive for you.

Answer (score 2):

It hurts performance since you are creating new jquery objects every time you do it.

Avoid it when possible.

Just create the jquery object and use that.

Comment: @kay , have you actually looked at the jquery.js file ? Have you thought about how much of it ends up in jQuery object each time you use `$()`? Try playing around with `console.dir()`.